# Scroll skipping h2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, I have a `nav nav-list` below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list well hidden-phone hidden-tablet" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="299">
        <li><a href="#about">About The Green Panda</a></li> 
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#logo">Logo & Brand</a></li> 
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li> 
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li> 
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work With Us</a></li>
      </ul>
```

The `href` are linked to `h2` on the page. When you click on the link it skips the h2 and doesn't display it when you scroll to it. I have created a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YNRWp/

I can not figure out how to fix this. I believe it has something to do with the fixed navbar but I can't figure out what it is. This is what I'm wanting it to do (notice the header at the top of each section: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global

Comment: Take a look . In your code (your fiddle) you have repeated  Ids ( prependedInput). You shouldn't .

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question you should accept (and possibly upvote) David's answer.

Comment: **madth3:** I am posting the solution to aid upcoming viewers of my question (the purpose of the site) I never noticed you could up vote and accept the answers provided, I have now since you mentioned and conducted those wishes! Thank you for notifying me of this possibility and happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser scrolls to your H2, it doesn't take into account that the header is floating on top of it.  You can work around this by adding some "padding-top" to your H2's.  Try add this...

`h2 { padding-top: 50px; }`